Requesting authors to add my name to a research paper after acceptance of publishing it in a journal
I contributed to CrowdMath 2021 Paper as a user on a website called ArtOfProblemSolving under my alias JapanMO2020. It turns out that the work was published in an ArXiV paper this year in 2024 and will be published in 2025 according to the ScienceDirect journal date. However, I have instead been acknowledged in the acknowledgement section of the paper here, with my alias. I want to request the main author of the paper to include my acutal name as a co-author in ArXiV and the journal it was submitted to.
Is this valid for the authors on the current edition to do so? The reason why my name was not published in the first place was due to a plethora of reasons and my fault. However, I would love to know if this is possible now.

See the arXiv rules. There are a couple of ways that a new version of a paper can be uploaded, though old versions generally remain.
But there are obstacles. Can you provide acceptable proof of your identity to the authors? It is easy to make claims.
It also seems unlikely that your contribution rises to the level of authorship, but the current authors will need to judge that. How much did you contribute to the intellectual content of the paper. You weren't involved in its inception, I'd guess.
But you might be able to get your acknowledgment pointed to your real name, both at arXiv and, more importantly, at subsequent formal publication.
It is possible, also, for authors to make changes after submission to journals, and probably after acceptance if done quickly, though  much harder after publication unless misconduct is alleged.

My impression is also that the acknowledged contribution, i.e. "proving Lemma 2.5 and collaborating on the proof of Lemma 2.1", (which at first glance seem to have relatively easy proofs) wouldn't normally rise to the level of coauthorship in mathematics without further involvement. Not sure if or how much the threshold might shift given that CrowdMath appears to be a project aiming to engage high school and college students in research.

Buffy, I have contacted both the authors of the paper to credit my work for the paper and will soon get response, but wanted to know if it is possible to add my name or not. I was involved in the proving of two key lemmas and contributed to more of the paper. I agree that it can only be judged by the authors of the paper but I have also requested them to add my name to the acknowledgement if not the list of authors. The lemma 2.1 was crucial to the progress of one section of the paper which makes me think I am eligible for authorship.

@Anyon I think that CrowdMath did not acknowledge authors from the 2020 edition. I believe I might have a chance here

There's a high chance this is too late. Authorship changes are a big deal, and even changing it after submission but before acceptance could involve substantial procedures.
However, it's possible. As you can see from the standard COPE flowchart, you'll inevitably need 1) an explanation as to why you were left out originally, and 2) the agreement of all current authors. Then the journal, if they agree, will publish a correction.
First step is to contact all the current authors and get them to agree you deserve to be an author. If that's not possible, you are likely screwed (unless you can get their institution to arbitrate in your favor).

I would start with politely asking the authors if they agree with adding you as a coauthor. If the paper is accepted but not yet published, this should be relatively easy. It may require written statements from all the authors, but in your case there are only a few of them. Replacing the arXiv is also a matter of a few clicks. So it all boils down to the willingness of the current authors to do so and your ability to prove that you are that person known under the nickname. Replacing your name in the acknowledgements should be no problem at all, I cannot imagine why anyone would be reluctant to do it.
